# Random chapter goes out of numbering

Tags: numbering, chapters, overleaf

I am trying to write a chaptered document using this template : [Latex Thesis Template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)

Each chapter being in an independent `tex` file and gathered up by the `main.tex` file.

I don't know why I didn't do any re-setup of the `main.tex` file and I obtain this output in the table of content page:

[image: Page random reset page numbering]

What could cause this ?

The top of every chapter starts like:

```
% Chapter Template

\chapter{MRI for Cardiac Imaging}

\label{Chapter3}


\section*{Introduction}
```

and end up without anything in particular. Where should I look to get more information and fix this issue?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What happens when you don't use the chapter template? Instead, create a new file (say, `FirstChapter.tex`) and copy everything in `Chapter1.tex` into there.

Comment: Interesting, if I just copy and paste the content of the chapter in a blank `tex` file I get the same result, the numbering resets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the package soul `\usepackage{soul}` and more precisely the command `\hl{}` was generating an error (somehow) and messing with the chapter numbering in the table of content. Removing the `\hl{}` where it was employed solved it!

Comment: There is no `\usepackage{soul}` in the template...

Comment: I added it because I wanted to highlight the section that needed some re-work.